# Objective C convert format date string

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have the following string :

2016-02-13T00:00:00

I would like to format it to remove the time from it.

I use the following code :

```
NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [DateFormatter dateFromString:periodStr];

NSString *formattedDate = [DateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

For some reason, after going through the NSDateFormatter, the variable date is null.

I do not understand. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: See Apple [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) for other issues (such as setting `locale`). Also, given that your string doesn't supply a timezone, you should identify what timezone was used (generally UTC) and set the `timezone` property, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your format, `@"yyyy-MM-dd"`, does not match the format of the string `"2016-02-13T00:00:00"`. Thus the NSDateFormatter cannot extract a date from this string.

You're basically omitting a step. What you want to do is start with a format that matches the input string, and extract the date from the string. Then set a format that matches the desired output string, and extract the string from the date.